# constructor ItemToPurchase in class ItemToPurchase cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, data-structures, constructor, get, set

Ive been looking through the forums but i cant seem to understand what exactly is my issue.
This is a classwork assignment and everything runs fine on my end. When i upload  my code into zybook for submission it outputs are correct, but im  getting errors with my set and get functions, under specific Unit tests.

```
"Tests item.setName("Chocolate Chips") and item.getName() == "Chocolate Chips"

Compilation failed
zyLabsUnitTest.java:5: error: constructor ItemToPurchase in class ItemToPurchase cannot be applied to given types;
      ItemToPurchase item = new ItemToPurchase();
                            ^
  required: String,int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error"
```

I cannot change the private fields to public as the assignment states these must be private. Here is my code if anyone is kind enough to take a look

```
package onlineshoppingcart;
import java.util.*;

public class OnlineShoppingCart {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Item 1");   
       System.out.println("Enter the item name:");
       String n;
       n = kb.nextLine();


       System.out.println("Enter the item price:");
       int p;
       p=kb.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Enter the item quantity:");
       int q;
       q=kb.nextInt();

       System.out.println();

       ItemToPurchase item;
       item = new ItemToPurchase(n, p, q);
       //item.setName("Chcolate Chips");//testing to see if set & get are ==
       //System.out.println(item.getName());//with my manual entry they are
       item.setName(n);
       item.setPrice(p);
       item.setQuantity(q);
     //fix me
     //item.getName();


       System.out.println("Item 2");
       kb.nextLine();//to stop out scanner from skipping input

       System.out.println("Enter the item name:");
       n=kb.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Enter the item price:");
       p=kb.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter the item quantity:");
       q=kb.nextInt();

       ItemToPurchase itemtwo;
       itemtwo = new ItemToPurchase(n,p,q);
       itemtwo.setName(n);
       itemtwo.setPrice(p);
       itemtwo.setQuantity(q);

       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("TOTAL COST");
       System.out.println(item.getName()
               +" "+ item.getQuantity()+" @ $"
               +item.getPrice()+" = $"
       +item.getPrice()*item.getQuantity());

        System.out.println(itemtwo.getName()
               +" "+ itemtwo.getQuantity()+" @ $"
               +itemtwo.getPrice()+" = $"
       +itemtwo.getPrice()*itemtwo.getQuantity());

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Total: $"+((
        itemtwo.getPrice()*itemtwo.getQuantity())+(
        item.getPrice()*item.getQuantity())));
    }


}


package onlineshoppingcart;

public class ItemToPurchase {

    private String itemName;
    private int itemPrice;
    private int itemQuantity;
    private ItemToPurchase(){


    String itemName = "null";
    int itemPrice = 0;
    int itemQuantity = 0;
}
    ItemToPurchase(String n, int p, int q){
        itemName = n;
        itemPrice=p;
        itemQuantity=q;
    }


public void setName(String n){
    itemName=n;

}

public void setPrice(int p){

        itemPrice = p;

}

public void setQuantity(int q){   
        itemQuantity = q;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.itemName;
}

public int getPrice(){
    return this.itemPrice;
}

public int getQuantity(){
    return this.itemQuantity;
}
}
```

Comment: Your no-arg constructor is marked private

Comment: The code you should be showing is not your class with your main method, since there you call the right constructor, but your zyLabsUnitTest.java class. There you call the default constructor, while you should call the one that takes parameters.

Comment: @DevilsHnd in the question, the OP states that the private must remain

Comment: Hmmm..missed that...thanks

Comment: ive tried making additional public constructors to only accept one of the values, so when there unit test runs, i thought that would work. Looks like im still having the same issue. Cant even check what there unit test actually looks like. Thanks for the tips guys.

Comment: @SemikCzupryna in your unit test, you call a constructor without parameters. There is only one constructor without parameters, and it is private, hence the Test class can't reach it. Just pass parameters in the constructor call of the Tests

Comment: I was trying to set values in a default constructor, removing them and leaving it empty fixed the issue